# Error no corre mi aplicación de .NET en el navegador

Tags: sql-server, .net, asp.net-web-api

Buen día tengo una Aplicación en .NET y estoy haciendo una api al momento de correrla no me corre correctamente la liga cuando mando a llamar. Este es mi codígo verfique conexion a base de datos y no tengo problemas pero cuando la corro no me genera el json que tendria que generar. estoy utilizando Swagger para ejecutar sin problemas pero al final si lo ejecuta pero no me manda a llamar nada de la base de datos.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            { 
                Title = "Swagger demo in core",
                Version = "V1",
                Description = "Swagger Demo for .net",
            });

           /* var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = ConfigurationPath.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath); */
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("default")));
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {

                string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "sagger v1");
                c.DocumentTitle = "Demo - Swagger in Core";

        });

       /* app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });*/
    }
```

Este es mi controlador

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<CompanyDTO>>> Get()
    {
        var company = await applicationDbContext.Company.ToListAsync();

        return mapper.Map<List<CompanyDTO>>(company);
    }
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name ="GetCompany")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CompanyDTO>> Get(int id)
    {
        var company = await applicationDbContext.Company.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.id_company == id);

        if (company == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return mapper.Map<CompanyDTO>(company);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(CompanyCreationDTO companyCreationDTO)
    {
        var company = mapper.Map<Company>(companyCreationDTO);

        applicationDbContext.Add(company);

        await applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        var dto = mapper.Map<CompanyDTO>(company);

        return new CreatedAtRouteResult("GetCompany",new { id = company.id_company}, dto);
    }
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Put(int id, CompanyCreationDTO companyCreationDTO)
    {
        var company = await applicationDbContext.Company.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c=> c.id_company == id);
        if (company==null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        mapper.Map(companyCreationDTO, company);

        applicationDbContext.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;

        await applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var company = applicationDbContext.Company.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.id_company == id);

        if (company == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        applicationDbContext.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        await applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

}

aqui adjunto mi controlador no se realmente si son las rutas o alguna parte que se me haya escapado cuando lo ejecuto todo esta muy pero no me carga la pagina me tira el error 404. pero al final no me refleja nada, ya confirme la conexion a la base de datos no hay problema.

Comment: Buen Día, Ya debugueaste el código para ver donde o que error te genera  ó para ver si al menos entra a tu controller la petición.

Comment: Buen día, fíjate que no me aparece ningún error mas que el 404, cuando mando a hacer el GET en el Swagger solo da este error= Error: response status is 404. cuando inicio la liga normal que seria = https://localhost:44376/api/company de igual forma el mismo error no me levanta nada.

Comment: entonces necesitas agregar el código de tu controller company, por que es donde no te esta detectando la ruta.

Comment: la ruta la tengo asi = [ApiController] [Route("api/company")] y el Get `[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<CompanyDTO>>> Get()
        {
            var company = await applicationDbContext.Company.ToListAsync();

            return mapper.Map<List<CompanyDTO>>(company);
        }`

Comment: segun la configuración de un proyecto nuevo, te falta en tu `public void Configure(`, la parte que tienes comentada pero `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });`

Comment: Lo verifique tenias razon, ahora el problema que tengo es que me sale este error,             var company = await applicationDbContext.Company.ToListAsync(); me sale un error 500 y me señala esa linea

Comment: debugea la app y revisa el error especifico, por que el error 500 es genérico  un error interno.

Comment: Tenias razón el problema era lo del public configure si gustas con la respuesta tengo otro problema pero lo hare en otra pregunta. gracias te agradezco bastante.